# How to create xml report of JaCoCo with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I have Android project.
And I am trying to use JaCoCo code coverage with Gradle.

This is my JaCoCo configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

project.afterEvaluate {

def buildTypes = android.buildTypes.collect { type -> type.name }
def productFlavors = android.productFlavors.collect { flavor -> flavor.name }

if (!productFlavors) productFlavors.add('')
productFlavors.each { productFlavorName -> buildTypes.each {
                      buildTypeName -> def sourceName, sourcePath
                      if (!productFlavorName) {
                      sourceName = sourcePath = "${buildTypeName}" }
else {
sourceName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName.capitalize()}"
sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}"
}

def testTaskName = "test${sourceName.capitalize()}UnitTest"

task "${testTaskName}Coverage" (type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
      group = "Reporting"
      description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."
      classDirectories = fileTree(
          dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${sourcePath}",
          excludes: [
             '**/R.class',
             '**/R$*.class',
             '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
             '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
             '**/BuildConfig.*',
             '**/Manifest*.*'
          ]
      )
      def coverageSourceDirs = [
          "src/main/java",
          "src/$productFlavorName/java",
          "src/$buildTypeName/java"
     ]
         additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
         sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
         executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
         reports {
            xml.enabled = true
            html.enabled = true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

}

But it generates only `.exec` files, **there are no xml or html**.

**What am I missing?** Are this lines not enough?

```
executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
         reports {
            xml.enabled = true
            html.enabled = true
        }
```

Comment: Did you notice that default place for coverage reports is `app/build/reports/jacoco/coverageReport`, it is not beside the `.exec` files that are located in `app/build/jacoco` ?

Comment: So, there are no any reports, right? But what is wrong?

Comment: were you able to solve this? i am seeing the same in my android project